# Imagine Whether Or Not

Tags: interrogatives, free-relative-clauses

I have this sentence using "*think*":

> I was ***thinking*** whether or not he has money that I can borrow.

is good English.  If I replace "*think*" with "*imagine*":

> I was ***imagining*** whether or not he has money that I can borrow.

Would this be okay English?

Comment: They're both correct grammatically, but the sentences have different connotations.

Comment: @TheIntern I have a feeling that while "think" could be used with two or more posibilities, "imagine" can only be used with one possibility or the other?

Comment: "Think" can be used when there is only one possibility, like "I think he has money that I can borrow.". "Imagine" is more like you are fantasizing or dreaming.

Answer (score 2):

Neither *think* nor *imagine* is used this way with *whether*.

To *think* X is to hold it as a strong idea or opinion that X is true or happened, and to *imagine* it is to form and subsequently hold such an idea or opinion. These do not suit well with *whether*, which implies uncertainty between two or more ideas or opinions.

Ordinarily we ***wonder*** whether X is true, to indicate that we raise the question in our minds; or if we ponder the question deeply we **consider** or *think **about*** whether it is true.

Comment: *"I'm going to think about whether or not he has money I can borrow."* is valid to say, but has a different connotation.  It suggests more that it's the thinker who will be making the decision--it doesn't express a curiosity.  It's as if they were a puppetmaster of some kind, who will examine his assets and then make the decision; the lending will be happening or not on the thinker's terms.

Comment: @HostileFork I agree about 90%; but "thinking about" **could** be *Hmm - I know he just got a promotion...but then he also just got a girlfriend...and he's been talking about buying a house...but on the other hand he owes me a big favour, he wouldn't have gotten that promotion if I hadn't rewritten his report...and he never spends any money on clothes....*

Comment: But the pattern "***be thinking whether*** ...." could definitely be found in substantial numbers on google.

Comment: @meatie See this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thinking+whether%2Fwondering+whether&year_start=1785&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28thinking%20whether%20/%20wondering%20whether%29%3B%2Cc0). It arose in the 1780s and surged in the early 19th century - by 1818 it was four or five times more common than *imagine* - but from 1820 on it declined rapidly and is now strictly colloquial. Avoid it.